# How to detect circle in a binary image

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing

**It is the original image:**
[image]

**And the after pre-processing the image**

- to gray
- do canny edge
- dilate
- erode
- bitwise_not

**The result become as below:**

[image]

**Now I want to detect all the filled circle in the above image, the result which I 
want:**

[image]

**I have tried something like this:**

```
MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
matOfPoint2f.fromList(contour.toList());
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(matOfPoint2f, approxCurve, Imgproc.arcLength(matOfPoint2f, true) * 0.02, true);
long total = approxCurve.total();
// now check the total if it was greater than 6, then it can be a circle
```

**And the result is like this: *Which is not something I want***

[image]

**Update:** *(includes more sample image)*

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: keep in mind that you are actually not looking for circles due to perspective. in your "what i want" image you have marked multiple objects that do not nearly look like circles. while other similar shapes have not been filled red. consider using images that suit your purpose better

Comment: Yes, the purpose is to detect and count how many pipes are there in image? that was my solution that mentioned in the question, I just look if there is more better solution that overcome that problem which my solution has.

Comment: Have you tried applying the Hough Circle Transform?

Comment: @TiagoCunha Yes I have tried, the result was not even the image above.

Answer (score 6):

> UPDATE: updating my solution using contours. you can find the solution
>   using Hough circles below this.

---

### **Using Contours method.**

I tried finding contours to mark pipes again today. Results I got with contour. I have filtered the results based on the contour length and area. But you can apply more constraints based on the images you have. It seems like I have overfitted the solution to this one image, but that is the only image I have access to. You can also play with laplacian/canny in place of adaptive threshold. Hope this helps :)

[image: Pipes using contour]

```
import cv2 as cv2

img_color = cv2.imread('yNxlz.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 0)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours

contour_list = []
for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01*cv2.arcLength(contour,True),True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    # Filter based on length and area
    if (7 < len(approx) < 18) & (900 >area > 200):
        # print area
        contour_list.append(contour)

cv2.drawContours(img_color, contour_list,  -1, (255,0,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('Objects Detected',img_color)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
```

---

### **Hough Circles method**

I tried taking your image and applied hough circles(opencv). I do not have Java setup, hence I used python. Here is the code and corresponding results I got.

Before that some tips to fine tune this.

- Important is preprocessing, a simple Gaussianblur got me very good improvement, so play with gaussian filter size.
- Since you already know the pipe radius/diameter, exploit that information. That is, play with minradius and maxradius param in Houghcircles.
- You can also play with mindist param if you know the minimum distance between the pipes.
- If you know the region where pipes could be present you can ignore false positive pipes detected in region other than that.

Hope this helps :)

Code I used

```
import cv2 as cv2

img_color = cv2.imread('yNxlz.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (7, 7), 0)

#Hough circle
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=15,
                     param1=50, param2=18, minRadius=12, maxRadius=22)

if circles is not None:
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(img_color, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(img_color, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imwrite('with_circles.png', img_color)

cv2.imshow('circles', img_color)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
```

And here is the result I got.

[image: Results with Hough circles]

Comment: Thanks sir for the reply! before I got your reply I also tried the hough circles, it gave the result something similar to your test result, but there was two problems. The fist problem it was very slow to not good for real time, the second problem was with the situation, e.g: when I give another image, then it will not work very good, so I look for the algorithms that can be use to detect an oval or circle in the contour it self, maybe so much fast than hough circles. Anyway your answer is good. Give a vote up!!

Comment: Welcome, do try to reduce the image size a little for speed improvement. But it does lead to some info loss. Okay, findcontours also might help. Wish you good luck. Will see if i experiment with findcontour and post another answer later in the day

Comment: @BahramdunAdil it might be possible to find a way of automatically adjusting the pipeline with hough circles in it. You might want to provide some more samples that differ from the one you provided to let people consider the possible variations in data.

Comment: I have updated the solution with contours. Have a look. I did not consider speed and i thought you are in better position to judge that.

Comment: @m3h0w +1 agree with you.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil you should add constraints to your imaging and lighting to help the image processing. if you want reliable pipe counts you should produce images that can be processed in a robust manner. otherwise you will end up with a lot of false positives and missed pipes as in this solution. you can't expect reliable output from some random snapshot.

Comment: @Piglet Thanks you, the last update was more better. I also edited the question and uploaded more samples.